# Verify cPanel Login credentials with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, cpanel

I have a form, where users have to enter a link to their cPanel URL, login username and password.
I want a button before the submit named as 'Verify Credentials', which will check whether these credentials are working or not.
Any Ideas, how to achieve this?

Comment: that kind of actions can be done with selenium. Have a look at that. https://applitools.com/tutorials/selenium-php.html

Comment: Analyze how the cpanel login works, what requests are send and what the response looks like (Using your browsers dev tools). Then send your own requests using the supplied user information and check the answer.